# Could linear network predict next elements of series?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Suppose I have numerical series, e.g.

```
0 -1 2 7 0 -1 2 6 0 -1 2 7 0 -1 2 6 0
```

Could linear network with 7 receptors predict next elements of this series?

I've just met such kind of tasks and have no any idea how to determine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a homework, so just a hint to get you started.

You can see that the series is probably meant to be periodical with period 8. So a network with 8 inputs could certainly work - it would just map the first input directly to output.

Now, if you give it just 7 inputs then the network has to essentially "remember" the whole period. You need to answer whether this is possible. In other words, you want to know whether the 7 inputs are linearly correlated to the 8th number which is the desired output.

All you need to know is nicely described for example in [Chapter 10 - Linear Neural Networks](http://people.whitman.edu/~hundledr/courses/M350S08/Ch10.pdf)

Comment: I highly appreciate your attempt to show me the right way, but actually I'm passing exam right now and highly need exact answer. Thank you)

Comment: I have an idea to set up a system of equations where we have inknown xi; i =1...7 and weights which we can get from series and then try to solve it:

Comment: `0x0-1x1+2x2+7x3+0x4-1x5+2x6+6x7=0` and so on, does it have sense?

Comment: That will probably get you a bit closer to the answer

Comment: just be careful about the equation, right now it looks like you created it for 8 inputs instead of 7 ;) so you're also missing the affine factor (+b in ax+b)